# React Native-Expo App Screen freezes after 5th Clicks -no error

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am writing my first Expo/React-Native(-Express-Mongoose) App and after the 5th clicks my Android Expo App freezes.(i cant click anymore, doesnt response). I have no error and I have no idea, what am I doing wrong.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Image, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';


export default function App() {

  const [click, setClick] = useState({ frage: "serviceallgemein", like: "", datum: "" });
  const [savebar, setSave] = useState({ savebar: false });
  const [thankyou, setthankyou] = useState({ thankyou: false });

  const handleClick4 = () => {
    setClick((prev) => ({
      ...click,
      like: 4,
      datum: new Date().toLocaleString(),
    }
    ))
    setSave((prev) => ({ savebar: true }))
  }
  const handleClick3 = () => {
    setClick((prev) => ({
      ...click,
      like: 3,
      datum: new Date().toLocaleString(),
    })
    )
    setSave((prev) => ({ savebar: true }))
  }
  const handleClick2 = () => {
    setClick((prev) => ({
      ...click,
      like: 2,
      datum: new Date().toLocaleString(),
    })
    )
    setSave((prev) => ({ savebar: true }))
  }
  const handleClick1 = () => {
    setClick((prev) => ({
      ...click,
      like: 1,
      datum: new Date().toLocaleString(),
    })
    )
    setSave((prev) => ({ savebar: true }))
  }

  const setAlarm = () => {
    setSave((prev) => ({ savebar: false }));
    setthankyou((prev) => ({ thankyou: true }));
  }





  useEffect(() => {
    //check if data already saved (megnezi hogy volt e mar az adat mentve(ha igen, akkor az ertek false lesz, kattintasra true)rerender eseten)
    if (savebar.savebar === true) {
      //if initiation-no save-megnezi hogy nem e inicializalo rendering e
      if (click.like != "") {
        //node connection?-megnezi hogy el a node kapcsolat
        const checkfetch = async () => await fetch('http://192.168.2.165:9000/like');
        checkfetch().then(res => res.text())
          .then(res => {
            if (res == "nodeisok") {
              const fetching = async () => await fetch('http://192.168.2.165:9000/like', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ frage: click.frage, like: click.like, datum: click.datum }),
              });
              fetching().then(
                setAlarm())
                .catch((error) => {
                  alert("No connection");
                })


            }
          }).catch((error) => {
            alert("No connection");
          });
      }
    }
    const setstatethankyou = () => { setthankyou((prev) => ({ thankyou: false })) };
    const timer = setTimeout(() => setstatethankyou(), 4000);
    return () => { clearTimeout(timer) }
  }
    , [click]
  )
  /* */
  return (<View style={styles.container}>
    {thankyou.thankyou == true ?
      <View style={styles.containerthankyou}>
        <Text style={styles.thankyou}>Vielen Dank!</Text>
      </View>
      :
      <View style={styles.containernormal}>
        <Text style={styles.frage}>Wie gefällt Ihnen unsere Service?</Text>
        <View style={styles.buttonbox}>
          <Pressable style={styles.buttons} onPress={handleClick4}><Text style={styles.smiley} ></Text></Pressable>
          <Pressable style={styles.buttons} onPress={handleClick3}><Text style={styles.smiley} ></Text></Pressable>
          <Pressable style={styles.buttons} onPress={handleClick2}><Text style={styles.smiley} ></Text></Pressable>
          <Pressable style={styles.buttons} onPress={handleClick1}><Text style={styles.smiley} >☹️</Text></Pressable></View>
        <StatusBar style="auto" />
      </View>}

  </View >
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 ...
```

I have tried to delete the timer-thankyou segment to check if setTimeout was wrong- no changes

Answer (score 1):

My bug was in the backend.

```
app.post('/send', function (req, res, next) {
var getfrage = req.body.frage;
var getlike = req.body.like;
//"2015-01-01T23:02"
var getdatum = req.body.datum;
var obj = { frage: getfrage, like: getlike, datum: getdatum };
createLike(obj);
res.end(); <---- This is what I forgot.
```

});

My fetch started everytime and doesn't end. I don't understand why, but after the 5th clicks i couldn't connect anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to track what's happening because some of the code is written in a confusing way. For instance, you're mixing the `async/await` pattern with the `.then` pattern, you should choose one or the other.

### Async/await

```
const statusResponse = await fetch('http://192.168.2.165:9000/like');
const statusText = await res.text();
if (res == "nodeisok") {
  try {
    const saveResponse = await fetch('http://192.168.2.165:9000/like', {...etc});
    setAlarm();
  } catch(error) {
    alert("No connection")
  }
}
```

### .then

```
const checkfetch = fetch('http://192.168.2.165:9000/like')
  .then(res => res.text())
  .then(res => {
    if (res == "nodeisok") {
      const fetching = fetch('http://192.168.2.165:9000/like', {...etc});
        .then(() => setAlarm())
        .catch((error) => alert("No connection"))
            }
          }).catch((error) => alert("No connection"));
    }
  }).catch((error) => alert("No connection"));
```

Another general suggestion is to use more specific state types, rather than objects with multiple properties. For instance, you could have `const [saveBarVisible, setSaveBarVisible] = useState(false);` and `const [rating, setRating] = useState(-1);`.

The real problem, as I see it, is that your code is more confusing than it needs to be and this makes it hard to find what the real problem and solution is. That said, if I had to guess, I would say the error is that `setAlarm` is not being called reliably, and so `saveBar` is false and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I appreciate every tips, I learn coding alone. My bug was suprisely in backend! I answered it below.

Comment: @BettiGem well done! When you can see what's happening with your network requests, it's easier to find where they're going wrong. Having your network requests nicely ordered can tell you where it's breaking down. As you discovered, an unresolved promise doesn't fail, it just stops everything. It's sometimes useful to handle timeouts for this reason. Libraries like RTK Query or Tanstack query can help with this.